# writing a image to a folder via imwrite in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, file-io

I try to write a image to a folder but imwrite has no input for specifying a folder name. Is there any other func. or way to store image to a folder. Maybe I amiss on imwrite if I do, I am sorry about it.

When I use a file name parameter like "folder1/folder2/img.jpg" it does not create folders accordingly and it just create a file named as "folder1/folder2/img.jpg"

I also try to use mkdir ahead in time but it also gives "Permission Denied" on console.

By the way I am using Linux. May be about permission problem?

Comment: Use `pwd` to find out in which directory you are. Do you have write permissions there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `filename` parameter doesn't mean *just the name* - you can give it a path, either absolute or relative, as part of the string.

```
imwrite(img,'my/folder/images/file','jpg')
```

for example.

Comment: when I do it in that way it creates a file named "my/folder/images/file.jpg" it does not create folders accourdingly

Comment: create the folders ahead of time (if it doesn't already exist) - you can use [mkdir](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mkdir.html)

Comment: I just used mkdir but it gives "Permission denied" on console.

Comment: Get yourself some write permissions in the target folder, then give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

The folder would just be specified in the file name, like this

```
imwrite(img, 'folder1/filename.tif','tif');
```

or if you want to use an absolute path.

```
imwrite(img, 'C:/Users/UserName/folder1/filename.tif','tif');
```

Check out wikipedia on [absolute and relative paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write the image into destination folder use the following code in MATLAB.

```
destinationFolder = 'C:\Users\Deepa\Desktop\imagefolder';
if ~exist(destinationFolder, 'dir')
  mkdir(destinationFolder);
end
baseFileName = sprintf('%d.png', i); % e.g. "1.png"
fullFileName = fullfile(destinationFolder, baseFileName); 
imwrite(img, fullFileName); % img respresents input image.

 I hope this answer might help someone.
```

Answer (score -1):

***this will open new figure to choose the path and format.***

[filename, ext, user_canceled] = imputfile

[image]