# save an image in a complete path

Tags: image, opencv, path, save

I am using OpenCV library and visual studio 2013. I would like just to save the result image in a complete path. It's ok for the same path but `c:\\...` doesn't work.
I tried to use both forward `\` and back `/`, the result looked the same.
Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

Mat src, dst;
float sum;

/// Load an image
src = imread("lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

if (!src.data)
{
    return -1;
}

// define the kernel
float Kernel[3][3] = {
    { 1 / 9.0, 1 / 9.0, 1 / 9.0 },
    { 1 / 9.0, 1 / 9.0, 1 / 9.0 },
    { 1 / 9.0, 1 / 9.0, 1 / 9.0 }
};
dst = src.clone();
for (int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++)
for (int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++)
    dst.at<uchar>(y, x) = 0.0;
//convolution operation
for (int y = 1; y < src.rows - 1; y++){
    for (int x = 1; x < src.cols - 1; x++){
        sum = 0.0;
        for (int k = -1; k <= 1; k++){
            for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++){
                sum = sum + Kernel[j + 1][k + 1] * src.at<uchar>(y - j, x - k);
            }
        }
        dst.at<uchar>(y, x) = sum;
    }
}

namedWindow("final");
imshow("final", dst);

namedWindow("initial");
imshow("initial", src);
vector<int> compression_params; //vector that stores the compression parameters of the image

compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY); //specify the compression technique

compression_params.push_back(100); //specify the compression quality

bool bSuccess = imwrite("filtre.jpg", dst, compression_params);//ok
    bool bSucccess = imwrite("D:/trunk/jpwl/Release/nouveau_dossier/filtre.jpg", dst, compression_params);// not ok
    bool bSuccces = imwrite("D:\trunk\jpwl\Release\nouveau_dossier\filtre.jpg", dst, compression_params);// not ok

waitKey();


return 0;
}
```

Comment: btw, unless that's an assignment for school, you should use filter2D() here instead of writing pixel loops

Answer (score 1):

Use:
"D:\trunk\jpwl\Release\nouveau_dossier\filtre.jpg" (with double backslash, Stackoverflow also shows a single backslash)

or

@"D:/trunk/jpwl/Release/nouveau_dossier/filtre.jpg" 
instead. A single \ is an ESC character.

Dick

Comment: it's ok thanks but where is the problem when i  use this path: imwrite("C:/Users/admin/Documents/Visual_studio_2013/filtre.jpg", dst, compression_params); i know visual_studio_2013 is false did you mind if you help me

Comment: Ok, I understand - does the link below help you further? Dick. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973070/writing-a-image-to-a-folder-via-imwrite-in-matlab